# How can I easily create templates for a custom asp.net Web Forms control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to make it so we have one code behind for a user control but different sites (and quite possibly pages) will need their own HTML template of that HTML.  The html also needs to be modifyable by front-end developers without a dll push.

Previously, I have done this by creating a standard ascx with code behind that binds all the controls.  I then have the front end developers make a copy of the ascx and change the markup of the new ascx (leaving the code behind definitions exactly matching from the original).  Then have a setting that tells the control which actual ascx to use, and everything hooks up correctly.

However, I am wondering if there are better ways to achieve this, especially since something as simple as deleting an asp control (like a label) that's not needed for one site will cause an exception)

In an ideal world I would prefer something more akin to MVC or MVP type of system, but I am stuck in pure, original webforms system that I need to add custom controls to.

Is there a better way to achieve templating than creating multiple ascx's sharing the same code behind?

Note that physical files for the templates are a must, so that we can track the templates in source control.

Comment: How modified are the themes? Are we talking something that could be easily implemented with an `OutlineColor` or `BackgroundUrl` property, or is it a complete overhaul on the design?

Comment: They could be completely different markup from one site to another, from what classes are used to where on the control certain html nodes are located

Comment: How about using [skins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)? (Probably not versatile enough?)

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't look versatile enough.  If we could have one well written HTML markup controlled via CSS that could work on all sites that would look to be the best bet, but we need more flexibility than that, including the possibility of changing the format a date is displayed (done via databinding the date property and displaying it in the ascx via code or in a frontend bound repeater)

Comment: How about making HTML templates that you can set via a public property on the control? So then the control would use the appropriate template?

Answer (score 1):

Given your constraints, I think you're on the right track with sharing the code-behind. One thing that sticks out in your requirements is the ability delete a control without breaking the code-behind. You could achieve this by adding an intermediate code-behind between the base class (your current code-behind) and the ascx.

**Base Class (your refactored code-behind)**

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseUC
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

' Define all page controls here
Public MustOverride Property lblPageTitle As Label

Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ' Check if control has been initialized by inheriting class
    If lblPageTitle IsNot Nothing Then
        lblPageTitle.Text = "Hooray"
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

**New site-specific code behind**

```
Partial Class controls_Sample
Inherits BaseUC

Public Overrides Property lblPageTitle As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label
    Get
        Return title
    End Get
    Set(value As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)
        title = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

**Site specific ASCX**

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Sample.ascx.vb" Inherits="controls_Sample" %>

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="title"></asp:Label>
```